# toggleSidebarVisibility when terminalFocus

Tags: visual-studio-code

My most used action is ctrl+b which toggles the sidebars visibility. However when I am focused in the terminal and I press Ctrl + b it types `^B` instead of toggling the focus.

I tried add this to my keybindings:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+b", "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility", "when": "terminalFocus" }
```

Notice the `terminalFocus` however it still types the `^B`, is it possible to make ctrl+b work when terminal is focused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the terminal captures the key input before vscode has a chance to handle it. According the vscode user and workspace settings [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace) there is an option to allow certain commands to skip the terminal. You are going to want to add your command to the list of commands to skip the shell:

```
"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
    "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    ...
],
```